# How to install imagick as extension in php with AMPPS and Mac OS 10.9.4

Tags: php, macos, imagick

I've managed to install imagick in my Mac. I can say that it is installed because I can now execute imagick "convert" command in command line and successfully resized an image.

But what i want is to make imagick as extension in PHP.

How can i do this? PHP documentation seems like for windows only

Please Help!

Comment: Step 1, install vagrant with a linux image. Step 2, install imagick extension in vagrant.

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal:

wget https://pecl.php.net/get/imagick-3.2.0RC1.tgz

unzip / untar

Type:

cd toyourdownload/imagick-3.2.0RC1/imagick-3.2.0RC1 (or just type cd enter a space and then drag the folder to the terminal)

/Applications/AMPPS/php/bin/phpize

./configure

make

sudo make install

restart apache.

I've tested this morning works fine: reference http://www.softaculous.com/board/index.php?tid=5246&title=switching_from_MAMP_to_AMPPS_for_redis#p19026